# browser is blocking Javascript window.open

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create a button that opens a new tab with the user's name. But in Chrome it always block the popup window. Is there way to do this without enabling popup windows?

```
<div class="box">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="meno" class="form-control" placeholder="Nick">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="tlacitko" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php
        if($_POST){
            $nick = $_POST['meno'];
            $hlasovat = "<script>window.open('https://czech-craft.eu/vote?id=16942&user=$nick') </script>";
            echo $hlasovat;
            unset($_POST);
        }
    ?>      
</div>
```

Comment: It's a users choice to turn the pop-up blocker on/off, you can't affect that.

Comment: on this site it works: [link](http://www.minecube.cz/) in right panel is `Hlasuj!` button. This button opens new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your HTML form to open in a new window/tab when submitted you can use:

```
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
```

instead of

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

For your code to work using this technique you will probably also need to do something like:

```
$hlasovat = "<script>window.location.href = 'https://czech-craft.eu/vote?id=16942&user=$nick' </script>";
```

or

```
$hlasovat = "<script>window.location.assign('https://czech-craft.eu/vote?id=16942&user=$nick') </script>";
```

or

```
$hlasovat = "<script>window.location.replace('https://czech-craft.eu/vote?id=16942&user=$nick') </script>";
```

instead of

```
$hlasovat = "<script>window.open('https://czech-craft.eu/vote?id=16942&user=$nick') </script>";
```